# Cannot create the foreign key "FK_ApplicationInfos_UserProfiles_UserProfileId" with the SET NULL referential action

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

How fix the problem ?
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIxWH.png)
 In Entity Framework Core, I'm attempting to create a system with 4 Db Models - User,UserProfile,Review, ApplicationInfo.
I tried a lot of things, well, I don’t understand the concept of how to fix the situation, I clearly gave cascade in modelOnCreate

**Model User**.

```
 public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

**Model UserProfile**

```
 public class UserProfile 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ApplicationInfo> ApplicationInfos { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    }
```

**Model Review**

```
public class Review
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string ImageLocation { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Rate { get; set; }
        //One(AppInfo) to Many(Review)
        public int ApplicationInfoId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationInfo ApplicationInfo { get; set; }
        //One(UserProfile) to Many(Review)

        public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }


    }
```

**Model ApplicationInfo**

```
public class ApplicationInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AppName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PublisherEmail { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string IconUrl { get; set; }
        public string PublisherName { get; set; }
        public string AllRatingCount { get; set; }
        public string AllRating { get; set; }

        //One(UserProfile) To Many(AppInfo)
        public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    }
```

**OnModelCreating**

```
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
                    HasOne<UserProfile>(s=>s.UserProfile).
                    WithOne(s=>s.User).
                    HasForeignKey<UserProfile>(s=>s.UserId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationInfo>()
                    .HasOne<UserProfile>(s => s.UserProfile)
                    .WithMany(s => s.ApplicationInfos)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
                    .HasOne<UserProfile>(s => s.UserProfile)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Reviews)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
                    .HasOne<ApplicationInfo>(s => s.ApplicationInfo)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Reviews)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


            }
```

Comment: The error message has **nothing** to do with deleting data.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Change OnModelCreating and change OnDelete for Review and AppInfo to Restrict(No Action)**

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOne<UserProfile>(s => s.Profile)
                .WithOne(s => s.User)
                .HasForeignKey<UserProfile>(s=>s.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationInfo>()
                .HasOne<UserProfile>(s => s.UserProfile)
                .WithMany(s => s.ApplicationInfos)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserProfileId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
                .HasOne<UserProfile>(s => s.UserProfile)
                .WithMany(s => s.Reviews)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserProfileId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
                .HasOne<ApplicationInfo>(s => s.ApplicationInfo)
                .WithMany(s => s.Reviews)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.ApplicationInfoId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        }
```